# Countifs and ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, countif

I'm trying to write some code that requires a cell value to be within a range of dates.
This is what I have written so far (albeit a few name changes for simplicity):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('[SheetA.xlsx]TabA'!A2:AA2, "submit", '[SheetA.xlsx]TabA'!B2:AB2, '[SheetA.xlsx]TabB'!**A9:A13**) >= 1, '[SheetA.xlsx]TabA'!C2, "")
```

Basically, if a cell in a row contains the word "submit" AND the cell to the right of it has a date (within a specific range of five days), I'd like the function to return the third cell of that row.

The range in bold is a range of dates.

This formula doesn't work when I use a range, but returns expected values when I enter a single date. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

As for `COUNTIF()` not finding a date in a range, if the range is consecutive, you can get around that like so:

```
COUNTIFS(A2:AA2, "submit", B2:AB2,">=" & LowestDate,B2:AB2,"<=" & HighestDate)
```

The problem there is that you're comparing a range to a range, so the whole range has to match the whole other range. This will always return false since the ranges are not even the same shape. When instead you compare a range to a single value, Excel automatically assumes you want true if the single value exists anywhere in the range.

It sounds like your other issue is that since `COUNTIFS()` does not return where it found "submit" and a date, the outer `IF` statement cannot determine where the third cell is.

If there's only going to be one submit, you could use `Match("submit",2:2,0)+2` to find the relative column of "submit" add 2 to it, and then use `ADDRESS()` to build the address of the third cell based on the row. Last you put that inside of an `INDIRECT()` to return the third cell. Something like:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A2),MATCH("submit",2:2,0)+2,1,1))
```

Note that this will not work for multiple matches as you're returning the first value `MATCH()` finds.

I use `ROW()` because `ADDRESS()` may not fill the row series very well when you drag the formula down a column if you use a plain row number.